# How to convert data format "YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" to "dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm:ss" using javascript?

Tags: javascript

*I have datetime column (format in `YYYY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) in my database.*

*I need to convert it into `dd-mm-YYYY hh:mm:ss` format.*

*How can i do? Help me.*

Comment: Are you accessing the db from a server side script? If so, do it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure, how to get db value in javascript, but if you have `data` in javascript variable then you can do this way

```
var date_arr = "2014-11-26 05:04:13".split(" ");
var date_aar2 = date_arr[0].split("-");
var new_date = date_aar2[2] + "-" + date_aar2[1] + "-" + date_aar2[0] + " " + date_arr[1];
console.log(new_date);
```

Comment: Good. This is more simple way, when compared with my answer.

Comment: @Barthee your answer is also good, but my answer good for beginners level user

Answer (score 0):

Split the datetime column and concat using comma and colon like below.

```
var date_time = "DATETIME".split(/-|\s|:/);  // Here DATETIME is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
var date1 = new Date(arr[2]+"-"+arr[1]+"-"+arr[0]+" "+arr[3]+":"+arr[4]+":"+arr[5]);
alert(date1)
```

***Result : 26-11-2014 06:12:56***

Answer (score 0):

```
function change(time) {
    var r = time.match(/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)(.*)$/);
    return r[3]+"-"+r[2]+"-"+r[1]+r[4];
}
var valuee = change("2014-02-14 03:00:00");

alert(valuee);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there isn't a way in which you can convert time formats in JavaScript by default, however you can achieve the requested result with the following function:

```
var input = "2000-12-24 12:30:59";

var date = new Date(input);

var output = "";
if(date.getDate()<10){
    output += "0";    
}
output += date.getDate() + "-";
if(date.getMonth()<10){
    output += "0";    
}
output += date.getMonth() + "-";
output += date.getYear() + " ";
if(date.getHours()<10){
    output += "0";    
}
output += date.getHours() + ":"
if(date.getMinutes()<10){
    output += "0";    
}
output += date.getMinutes() + ":";
if(date.getSeconds()<10){
    output += "0";    
}
output += date.getSeconds();

alert(output);
```

Please check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp